# Mouse movement in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, events, mouseevent, mouse

I was wondering if in nodejs we can get the mouse position.
It's such a simple quick question but i just can't find a yes or no answer.

So the simple question is can i get mouse position using native node?

Also it would be good to not think of node as a server side language for this question.

Node can be run any where. Hence node webkit. This is a webkit application but it's node running in the back end.

I just want to track mouse. Problem is if the mouse goes off the page it's now untrackable.
but i want to track it outside the window as well.

Comment: nvm i figured it out. I can now track mouse off the page as well

Answer (score -2, accepted):

client side:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].onmousemove = function(eventData) {
    iosocket.send("mousemove", eventData);
}
```

sever side:

```
socket.on('message', function(action,p2) {
    if ("mousemove" == action) {
       /* YOUR CODE GOES HERE */
    }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I've been working on a module for getting the mouse position, [RobotJS](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs).

Example code:

```js
var robot = require("robotjs");

//Get the mouse position, retuns an object with x and y. 
var mouse=robot.getMousePos();
console.log("Mouse is at x:" + mouse.x + " y:" + mouse.y);

//Move the mouse down by 100 pixels.
robot.moveMouse(mouse.x,mouse.y+100);

//Left click!
robot.mouseClick();
```

Comment: Amazing library. I found it going well with https://github.com/WilixLead/iohook  Basically `iohook` reads user actions, while `robotjs` controls them.

Answer (score -3):

Node runs on the server side, the mouse is on the client side. 
What you can do is use sockets or something like that and send the mouse position to the server.

Comment: Node.js can also run on the client side. Then you would make a call to the localhost where the node server is running.